# Open document in an already-launched Xorg application from bash

Tags: bash, xorg

**Is there a way to tell an already running x-program to open a file from bash?** (I.e. without invoking a new instance of the program.) While I am asking this question in the context of `xstata-mp`, I am interested more generally if this kind of solution exists **in general** for Xorg applications.

I have an x-application (`xstata-mp`, proprietary, which is salient to this question as you will learn) which runs swell. I have managed to make a nice launching script that first checks whether `xstata-mp` is already running, and if it is, brings it to the foreground, and otherwise launches it. Much like [the accepted answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127284/command-to-launch-an-application-or-to-show-its-window-if-already-launched).

My problem is that sometimes I want to open a **document** used by `xstata-mp` (e.g., a `.dta` data file, a `.do` script file, a `.sthlp` help file, etc.). If I double click on such a file's icon, or select the icon and hit `<ENTER>` while `xstata-mp` is already running, the launch script gets called (it is referenced in the `exec` part of `xstata-mp`'s `.desktop` file) and `xstata-mp` is raised to the top of the visible windows, but without opening the document.

For what it is worth, checking with `pidof` it appears that `xstata-mp` **does not** launch a new `xstata-mp` process if I open multiple documents within it (e.g., using `<CTRL>-O`); contrast with, say, `Firefox` and multiple tabs/sites.

Here is the launch script I would like to modify:

```bash
# Check if xstata-mp v17 is running
exit_code_pidof_xstata_mp=$(pidof /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp)

# if xstata-mp v17 IS NOT running, then launch it with argument $1
if [ -z "$exit_code_pidof_xstata_mp" ]
  then
    /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp -q $1; exit >/dev/null
 # but if xstata-mp v17 IS running, then bring it to front instead
 else
  wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"; exit > /dev/null
  fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YES: There is a way to tell an already running x-program to open a file from bash!**

So, following a tip from StataCorp's technical support folks, it turns out that [`xdotool`](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool) (which can be installed with `sudo apt install xdotool`, if it is not already on your system) offers a solution to exactly the kind of problem in my question. From the project website:

> `xdotool` lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11’s XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.
>
> ⚠️ Note: If you are using Wayland, please be aware this software will not work correctly. ⚠️
>
> With `xdotool`, you can search for windows and move, resize, hide, and modify window properties like the title. If your window manager supports it, you can use `xdotool` to switch desktops, move windows between desktops, and change the number of desktops.

To solve my problem with `xdotool`, I needed to create an `xdotool` script which I am calling `statadoc.xdo`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/xdotool
search --name "Stata/MP"
type --window %1 '$1 ' '$2'
key --window %1 Return
```

A few comments about this short script:

1. The path may be something other than `/usr/bin/xdotool`, so be sure to confirm that with `which xdotool` or similar.
2. The second line will partially match the name `"Stata/MP 17.0"` with the string supplied above. This is useful, so that, for example, upgrading the version to 17.1, or 18.x won't break the script. The `search` command identifies the X-application window I want to interface with.
3. `xdotool` scripts accept arguments, following `bash`-like `$1`, `$2`, etc. conventions.
4. The `type` command literally types the provided text—in my case, the contents of the two supplied `$1` and `$2` string arguments in the 1st (and in my case only) window identified by the `search` command on line 2.
5. The `key` command sends an `<ENTER>` (or `<RETURN>` if you prefer) to the same Stata window.

Now let's look at my modified launch script, which calls `statadoc.xdo` in the third to last line (I have added a section in front to recognize whether the supplied argument indicates particular Stata file types—different use commands are needed to gracefully handle each… my example is not complete, but these are the file types I use in the majority of my work):

```bsh
# Check whether there IS NOT an argument. If not, do nothing.
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    break
 # Otherwise, set prefix to default value, and then check 
 # whether file name ends in .hlp, .sthlp, .ado, .do, or .gph
 else
  prefix="use "
  if [ ${1##*.} = "hlp" ] || [ ${1##*.} = "sthlp" ] || [ ${1##*.} = "ado" ] || [ ${1##*.} = "do"  ]
    then
      # If the filename DOES end in one of those four prefixes then
      # change prefix to "doedit" so Stata opens the document with 
      # the do-file editor.
      prefix="doedit "
    fi
  # If the filename ends in .gph, then change prefix to "doedit" so 
  # Stata opens the document with the graph viewer/editor.
  if [ ${1##*.} = "gph" ]
    then
      prefix="graph use "
    fi
  break
  fi

# Check if xstata-mp v17 is running
exit_code_pidof_xstata_mp=$(pidof /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp)

# if xstata-mp v17 IS NOT running, then launch it with argument $1
if [ -z "$exit_code_pidof_xstata_mp" ]
  then
    /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp -q $1; exit >/dev/null
 # but if xstata-mp v17 IS running, then bring it to front instead
 else
  # First, call statadoc.xdo with the prefix as the first argument, 
  # and the supplied file path as the second argument 
  /usr/share/stata17/bin/statadoc.xdo "$prefix" " $1"
  wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep /usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"; exit > /dev/null
  fi
```

**Note: This is a solution for Gnome running on Xorg.**

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should find out the correct command to open your document. So try to run the following command and see what you get.

```
/usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp --help
```

Of course this is the critical part. And here you rely solely on the functionality of your program. If it does not offer that option, well, then you cannot do it, **because all a bash can ever do is start another program**. From the 9.4 MB user manual with 399 pages I downloaded from [StataCorp LLC](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u.pdf), there was not a single hint on how to use `xstata-mp`.

Maybe the `-q` option is already what you want. But let's assume the right option to add another document to an already running instance of `xstata-mp` would be `-a` (like in VS Code: `code -a`). Then all you have to do, is to add the following line below your `else` statement:

```
/usr/local/stata17/xstata-mp -a "$1"
```

It would open your document and show the current window now.

Comment: Thanks, mark. +1 I did indeed already read `xstata-mp --help` and also the things not documented there (like the `doedit` argument) in the official documentation. I feared an answer like yours might be in the offing, but posed my question in the hope that there might be some interface standard for Xorg apps along the lines of my request. (If there is, argument `-a` ain't it, by the way. ;). (Also: the `-q` option is mos def irrelevant to my concerns here.)

Comment: Hey mark. I have just learned about, and am playing with `xdotool` which is allows one to manipulate (key strokes, text, pointer input, windows, some related variables, etc.) Xorg programs. When I get my script edited to working, I will compose an answer, but wanted to let know there is a solution for Xorg applications in general! :)))

Comment: Ok, see my answer. :)